# jQuery: object checked property won't update

Tags: jquery, events

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/yssWp/

Has it always been the case that the jQuery object doesn't update on attribute change?

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="cb"
   onclick   = "getVal('click')"
   onchange  = "getVal('change')"
   onmouseup = "getVal('mouseup')"
/> Foo
```

```
var global = jQuery('#cb');
function getVal(msg){

   var local = jQuery('#cb');
   var s     = '      ';

   alert( 'Event: ' + msg + '\n'
        + s + s + s + s + s + ' _local_' + s + s + '_global_\n'
        + ".is(':checked')\t\t " + t(local.is(':checked'))   + t(global.is(':checked'))  + '\n'
        + ".attr('checked')\t "  + t(local.attr('checked'))  + t(global.attr('checked')) + '\n'
        + ".prop('checked')\t "  + t(local.prop('checked'))  + t(global.prop('checked')) + '\n'
        );
}


function t(val){
    var l = (val+'').length;
    return (val + '' + (l>'false'.length?'\t':(l='checked'.length?'\t\t':'\t\t\t\t')));
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I would like to see what the outcome of this is.

Comment: I thought that the property would always update, but I was trying to cache the checkbox globally and discovered that the checked property wasn't updating :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue was user error, the global should be assigned after the DOM has loaded:

#### From:

```
var global = jQuery('#cb');
function getVal(msg){
...
```

#### To:

```
var global;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
   global = jQuery('#cb'); 
});

function getVal(msg){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your .jsFiddle:

**global** is not updating because its only being assigned once - at the start. never any time after that, unless you reload the page.

**local** gets assigned and displays correctly because getVal() is run 3 times for every click.  There's nothing in getVal() that assigns **global** in any way, so global stays the same as it was before any click happens.

Comment: I don't think that's completely accurate as there would be no benefit to caching and it'd be inefficient.  The HTML Object should be assigned to the jQuery Object and it should use that to look up the DOM property.  The above should work for both `local` and `global`.

Comment: There might be something more going on.  If I place the JS in the body, it'll work, but if I keep it in the head it won't.. that leads me to think it's something to do with the DOM not ready yet.